# Translating who is coming to your home at Easter

Tags: translation, personal-pronoun

> Eng:Alex, who is coming to your house for Easter?
>
> De: "Alex, wer kommt zu Ostern zu dir nach Hause?"

I'm having difficulties understanding the German sentence. Here are more questions:

1. Where did the possessive 'your' go in the German sentence?
2. Could the usage and placement of 'dir' being explained?

Comment: I have a feeling most of your questions here boil down to "Why can't I translate my English sentence literally, word by word, to German?". The answer usually is: That's just how the two languages work, it's normal for them to be different.

Comment: They are inherently different and exist as their own thing, but the difficulty I face and question itself is how a person who learned English first could understand German second by understanding the differences between the two languages.

Answer (score 2):

Both questions have the same answer: the English expression "coming to your house" in the sense of visiting you at home corresponds to the German expression "zu dir nach Hause kommen".

If the sense were rather to walk up to your house, for example to have a look at how nicely it is decorated, the corresponding German expression would be "zu deinem Haus kommen". For a native German speaker this wording definitely implies staying outside and not entering said house.

Comment: The phrase *nach Hause* isn't even grammatical on its own since the dative of *Haus* is just *Haus*, at least in modern German. It's pointless to try to explain such phrases in terms of modern grammar; they'd be idioms except that the meaning is clear even if the grammar is obsolete.